# Android - Alert Dialog issue in GenyMotion

Tags: android, genymotion

I am new in android programming and I want to make an alert dialog project.my xml file is ok but when i open the app in genymotion it does not show the alert dialog.this is my java codes:

```
package karimi.afshin.alertdialog;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void open(View view){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure,You wanted to make decision");

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You clicked yes button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog=alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

and this is my xml file:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Alert Dialog"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="@color/background_floating_material_dark" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Tutorialspoint"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:textColor="#3db226"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/abc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ALERT DIALOG"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

I want it to be like this picture but it does not show the dialog box!

[image]

Thanks:)

Comment: where did you call your `open` method? There is no OnClickListener setted or onClick in the button layout. If you have any problem I can make you an answer.

Comment: I dont know I write it from tutorial.How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi check my answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change anything in your code. Just add `android:onClick="open"` in your Button layout. Like this:

```
...
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ALERT DIALOG"
        android:onClick="open"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response.it was my first android experience...:)

Answer (score 0):

try this , 
first you have to make onclick to the button that open the dialog ,

something like this in **onCreate** method

```
Button btn
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                TestDialog dialog= new TestDialog ();
                dialog.show(fm,"fragment name");
}
```

and now you have to create new class name TestDialogextends like this

```
public class TestDialog extends DialogFragment  {


public TestDialog () {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout."example.xml", container, false);

//declare your views here like buttons or edit text  
    return rootView;}
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), getTheme());
    final View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.actionoption, null);
    dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.action_settings));
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    return dialog;

}
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getDialog().setTitle("Actions Option");


}}
```

hope this help for any question tell me in comment

Comment: but I want to know that how I can call the open  method?

Comment: what is the open method ??? i cant understand ? your question about the picture and this solution for the picture ? what is ?

Comment: I mean i dont want to make many changes in codes.can we correct it with small changes?